# Register document type

Tags: objective-c, macos, applescript, aquaticprime, applescript-objc

How do I register my application to be the default application to open "aidelicense" files?  I'm using the AquaticPrime Framework and the AquaticPrime Developer application to make licenses.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to read up on the document-based architecture:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/Documents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000006-BAJJJHEG

In particular, you need to define `CFBundleDocumentTypes` in your application's .plist file, then the Finder just magically knows about the association when it encounters your .app bundle, such as when the user drags it into /Applications, or drags the icon into the dock.